# Error `Template parameter names *must* be separated`

Tags: javascript, mithril.js

I am using mithril.js in frontend application and backend application is running on ipv6 environment.

Calling post ajax request to backend using mithril.js.

```
async post(url, body = {}) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            m.request({method: 'POST', url, body}).then((data) => {
                resolve(data);
            }).catch((err) => {
                reject(err.message);
            });
        });
}
```

Backed url is like this: http://[340f:c0e0:1d1:5gc0:g4fs:2::]:22923/backend.

But getting this error `Template parameter names *must* be separated` while calling backend api.

Answer (score 4):

### Explanation of the error

Based on [the documentation of `m.request()`](https://mithril.js.org/request.html), you can specify [dynamic URLs](https://mithril.js.org/request.html#dynamic-urls):

> Request URLs may contain interpolations:
>
> ```js
> m.request({
>     method: "GET",
>     url: "/api/v1/users/:id",
>     params: {id: 123},
> }).then(function(user) {
>     console.log(user.id) // logs 123
> })
> ```
>
> In the code above, `:id` is populated with the data from the `params` object, and the request becomes `GET /api/v1/users/123`.
>
> Interpolations are ignored if no matching data exists in the `params` property.
>
> ```js
> m.request({
>     method: "GET",
>     url: "/api/v1/users/foo:bar",
>     params: {id: 123},
> })
> ```
>
> In the code above, the request becomes `GET /api/v1/users/foo:bar?id=123`

Since your backend URL contains colons, it's interpreted as being a dynamic URL.

According to [the documentation of `m.buildPathname()`](https://mithril.js.org/buildPathname.html), `m.request()` uses `m.buildPathname()` internally to process dynamic URLs.

The beginning of `m.buildPathname()` contains the following check regarding parameters of a path template (dynamic URL = path template populated with path parameters):

```js
if ((/:([^\/\.-]+)(\.{3})?:/).test(template)) {
    throw new SyntaxError("Template parameter names *must* be separated")
}
```

(Source: https://github.com/MithrilJS/mithril.js/blob/v2.0.4/mithril.js#L1288-L1292)

And, again, since your backend URL contains colons, this is where you are getting the error. (You can verify this by trying to run `m.buildPathname('http://[340f:c0e0:1d1:5gc0:g4fs:2::]:22923/backend')` – you'll get the same error.)

### How to fix it

Since you can't get away from that regex check at the beginning of `m.buildPathname()`, your best bet might be to use a dynamic URL. Like so:

```js
m.buildPathname(':url...', { url: 'http://[340f:c0e0:1d1:5gc0:g4fs:2::]:22923/backend' })
// => http://[340f:c0e0:1d1:5gc0:g4fs:2::]:22923/backend
```

Or when applied to your code:

```js
async post(url, body = {}) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    m.request({method: 'POST', url: ':url...', body, params: {url}}).then((data) => {
      resolve(data);
    }).catch((err) => {
      reject(err.message);
    });
  });
}
```

Or alternatively you can specify the (dynamic) URL as the first argument of `m.request()`:

```js
async post(url, body = {}) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    m.request(':url...', {method: 'POST', body, params: {url}}).then((data) => {
      resolve(data);
    }).catch((err) => {
      reject(err.message);
    });
  });
}
```

Notice that there are three dots after the path parameter `:url`. Otherwise its value would be escaped/encoded. This is mentioned in [the documentation of path handling](https://mithril.js.org/paths.html). Example:

```js
m.buildPathname(':url', { url: 'http://[340f:c0e0:1d1:5gc0:g4fs:2::]:22923/backend' })
// => http%3A%2F%2F%5B340f%3Ac0e0%3A1d1%3A5gc0%3Ag4fs%3A2%3A%3A%5D%3A22923%2Fbackend
```

#### Handling URL parameters

As mentioned in the other answer, if the URL contains parameters, the question mark will be duplicated:

```js
m.buildPathname(':url...', { url: 'https://example.com/foo?bar=baz' })
// => https://example.com/foo??bar=baz
//                           ^^
```

One way to solve that would be to include the parameters in the path template:

```js
const url = 'https://example.com/foo?bar=baz'
const [baseUrl, params] = url.split('?')
const template = ':baseUrl...' + (params ? `?${params}` : '')
m.buildPathname(template, { baseUrl })
// => https://example.com/foo?bar=baz
```

However, if there are colons in the URL parameters, there's a possibility that you'll get the same error as originally ("Template parameter names *must* be separated").

There might be a way to solve this, but the previous code sample is already quite complex for this relatively simple use case. Which leads us to:

### Alternative solution: don't use `m.request()`

[`m.request()`](https://mithril.js.org/request.html) is just "a thin wrapper around `XMLHttpRequest`." It "returns a promise and triggers a redraw upon completion of its promise chain."

If `m.request()` is difficult to work with due to using IPv6 URLs (or for other reasons), it can be easier to use something else for doing XHR requests. You could for example use [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) – just remember to call [`m.redraw()`](https://mithril.js.org/redraw.html) at the end (`m.request()` does this automatically).

Sure, `m.request()` does more than just calls `m.redraw()` at the end ([see the docs](https://mithril.js.org/request.html)), but it's also okay to use something else.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks `mts knn` for the reply. We have implemented your solution however we faced below issues.
Question mark is passing two times in http url of api. Please find attached below screenshot.
[image]

In order to fix this problem, please find the updated code below

```
async post(url, body = {}) {
    var queryIndex = url.indexOf('?');
    var httpPart = url.slice(0,queryIndex);
    var finalUrl = url.replace(httpPart,":url..."); 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       m.request({method: 'POST', url: finalUrl, body, params: {url: httpPart}}).then((data) => {
                resolve(data);
            }).catch((err) => {
                reject(err.message);
            });
        });
 }
```

You can also provide efficient solution If any.

Comment: Good catch. I updated my answer with a similar solution as yours and also with an alternative solution (don't use `m.request()`).